# typeid pointer and reference comparison difference?

Tags: c++, casting, typeid

Whilst I was messing around with `typeid` I noticed some odd behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Pointer comparison: " << (typeid(const int*) == typeid(int*))
        << "\nReference comparison: " << (typeid(const int&) == typeid(int&)) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> Pointer comparison: 0
>
> Reference comparison: 1

In the first case, `typeid` correctly suggests that a pointer to a constant value is a different from a pointer to a non-constant value. However, `typeid` then seems to indicate that a reference to a constant value is the same as a reference to a non-constant value.

Why does `typeid` give different results with regards to pointers and references?

Comment: You might be interested in `std::is_same_v<const int&, int&>` .  The purpose of `typeid` is to work with run-time polymorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is defined by C++17 [expr.typeid]/4:

> When `typeid` is applied to a *type-id*, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the *type-id*. If the type of the *type-id* is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the **cv-unqualified** referenced type.

Which is saying that `typeid(const T&)` and `typeid(T&)` both give the same result as `typeid(T)`.

Furthermore, point /5 also covers that `typeid(T)` is the same as `typeid(const T)`. There are not separate flavours of `typeinfo` for reference-types and const/volatile qualified types. [See cppreference summary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Comment: I edited to add emphasis on the important part.